# How can I deduce a day for a date object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

How can I deduce a day for a date object in JavaScript?

Example:

If I assig a date into an object as below:

```
var date_value = this.cfg.getProperty(cfgPageDate);
```

and the date format in date_value as below:

```
Fri May 29 2009 00:00:00 GMT+1000 (AUS Eastern Standard Time)
```

how can I deduce a day from this object so that the object date will become as below:

```
Thu May 28 2009 00:00:00 GMT+1000 (AUS Eastern Standard Time)
```

Comment: "Reduce", not "deduce". I found this question very confusing.

deduce means to infer. reduce means to subtract/take away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var dat = new Date('2009/05/29');
alert (dat.setDate(dat.getDate()-1));
```